# Как отправить скриншот, полученный из AS3 без сохранения файла на сервере?

Tags: actionscript-3, php, email, actionscript

Требуется: отправить из as3 емейл со скриншотом экрана. Как сделать это без сохранения файла на сервере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SMTPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27) class?

Comment: Спасибо, похоже то, что надо.